# Turning off a postDelayed Handler

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, timer, handler

My app starts with a title screen, then runs the game activity when the user touches the title screen.

I ALSO want it to start after 3 seconds even if the user didn't touch the screen.

The timer works BUT - the trouble is, when they touch the screen before the timer acts, the game comes up then comes up AGAIN when the timer starts it.

Here's the Kotlin code

```
class TitleActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    var t = Handler()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_title2)

        titleVersionTextView.setText("V." + VERSION)

        t.postDelayed({
            val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
            finish()
        }, 3000.toLong())

        TitleActivityLayout.setOnClickListener() {
            // t.removeCallbacks(r) // //timer. .purge() .cancel() .isCanceled()
            val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create a Runnable variable:

```
val runnable = Runnable {
    val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(i)
    finish()
}
```

and then:

```
t.postDelayed(runnable, 3000)
```

Now you can remove it as:

```
TitleActivityLayout.setOnClickListener() {
    t.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(i)
}
```